# Plone: default display for new created content

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a browser view my_custom_display, that can be selected for folders using the menu: Display -> my_custom_display.

The problem appears after I select the custom display and I'm trying to create new objects inside the folder with this custom display.

By default all new items seems to have my_custom_display and my solution is to manually fix it with `/selectViewTemplate?templateId=folder_listing`.

What is the better solution for this situations? (Set a display only for the item itself not any new child inside it.)

(It's annoying because my browser view generates errors if used in wrong place. Yes, I can improve it, but...)

Update:
In `/portal_types/Folder/manage_propertiesForm` I added my_custom_display in Available view methods. I need it only for specific folders.

Comment: Does `my_custom_display` works only with a *specific* Folder or can be applied to any Folder?

Comment: Updated question. It can be applied to any folder, but I need it only for the folder I apply, not for any child of it.

Comment: In `/portal_types/Folder/manage_propertiesForm`, which view is set as `Default view method`?

Comment: folder_listing, but Fall back to default view? is not checked. Is this the option I search for?

Comment: Tested. It's not the check for `Fall back to default view`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by forcing layout setting on folder creation:

```
<subscriber
    for="Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.IATFolder
         Products.Archetypes.event.ObjectInitializedEvent"
    handler="my.package.globalhandlers.set_folder_listing_by_default" />
```

added in `configure.cfg`.
Then:

```
def set_folder_listing_by_default(folder, event):
    """ Set folder_listing as default Display for new created folders.
    """
    folder.setLayout('folder_listing')
```

Seems not nice, but it solved my issue. :)